# Error installing Blurilly gem on OSX 10.12.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode

When installing the blurrily gem, I get the following issue.

For reference I'm using:
rvm 1.29.1
ruby 2.1.7p400
rails 3.2.22.5

And I'm trying to install Blurrily 1.0.2.

The error:

```
/Users/jonkeenan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170525-
62993-1jexk35.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/jonkeenan/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.1.7@introhive/gems/blurrily-1.0.2/ext/blurrily
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/jonkeenan/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.1.7@introhive/gems/blurrily-1.0.2/ext/blurrily
make "DESTDIR="
compiling map_ext.c
compiling search_tree.c
compiling storage.c
storage.c:283:43: error: taking address of packed member 'refs' of 
class or structure 'trigram_map_t' may result in an unaligned pointer 
value [-Werror,-Waddress-of-packed-member]
   if (haystack->refs) blurrily_refs_free(&haystack->refs);
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
storage.c:405:24: error: taking address of packed member 'refs' of 
class or structure 'trigram_map_t' may result in an unaligned pointer 
value [-Werror,-Waddress-of-packed-member]
     blurrily_refs_new(&haystack->refs);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 2 errors generated.
 make: *** [storage.o] Error 1

 make failed, exit code 2
```

It looks like a c compile issue, but I'm not sure. 
I'm running a version of xcode that's using Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42) if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it appears that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/mezis/blurrily/issues/48) that the gem maintainers have not yet addressed.

As a workaround, it might be worthwhile to switch to a Vagrant/Docker development workflow until this is addressed upstream.